# Is Left associativity only for Postfix expression?

Tags: c, stack, postfix-notation

In case of evaluation of postfix expression , is the associativity always left to right?. If yes, why? If no, why?

Comment: Your question isn't awfully clear, but if I got your drift then you need only think about the power function (which is a binary function of two numbers).

Comment: Im trying to ask if a postfix expression is evaluated from left to right only?

Comment: Depends if you write in latin or arabic :D

Comment: Yes. A postfix expression is evaluate from left to right only. The associativity and operator precedence are built-in to how the expression is notated.

Comment: @meaning-matters Your link is about C operators, not postfix expressions.

Comment: @user207421 What link?